# KeyPressed recognized but the Image is not moving on my screen

Tags: java, keylistener

I have an Image that shows up on the screen and in that same class I added a KeyListener, so the keys are being recognized when I press them because I added print statements to say if they are pressed so that is not the issue. The problem is that the image will not move. Am i not supposed to call the repaint method at the bottom of my Keypressed method. I think there should be a way to update the image but i am unsure how to do this. Here is my code(I have more classes but i think they are unnecessary to the problem):

### Printer

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

    /**
     * This class is used to paint all the graphics onto the screen
     */
    public class Printer extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private Map map;
    private Character ch;
    private int scale;
    private Point imageP;
    private BufferedImage chImage;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> part;

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int speed;


    /**
     * Constructor it initializes all the variables and all the keyListeners
     * @param scale1 takes in a scale factor so it can multiply and scale everything else
     */
    public Printer(int scale1){
        scale = scale1;
        map = new Map();
        ch = new Character();
        imageP = ch.getPoint();
        chImage = ch.getImage();
        part = map.getPart();
        x = imageP.x * scale;
        y = imageP.y * scale;
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        width = ch.getWidth();
        height = ch.getHeight();
        speed = ch.getSpeed();
    }

    /**
     * used to paint all the rectangles and the character
     * @param takes in the graphics component to draw objects
     */
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(int i=0; i<part.size(); i++){
            Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(part.get(i));
            g.drawRect(temp.x, temp.y, temp.width, temp.height);
            g.fillRect(temp.x, temp.y, temp.width, temp.height);
        }

        g.drawImage(chImage, imageP.x*scale, imageP.y*scale, null);

    }


    /**
     * Moves the character left right up and down based on what keys you press
     * @param listens for keyevents to happen from the user
     */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            imageP.y += 1*speed;
        }
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            if(imageP.y <= height-33)
                imageP.y += 1*speed;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            if(imageP.y >=0+5)
                imageP.y -= 1*speed;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            if(imageP.x >=0+5)
                imageP.x -= 1*speed;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            if(imageP.x <= width-30)
                imageP.x += 1*speed;
            break;
        }
        repaint();      
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

### Character Class

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * Creates a image for a character and allows him to walk around the screen
 */
public class Character extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;
    private Point imageP;
    private int speed;
    private int scale;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    /**
     * Constructs the basics of a Character with minimal info just mainly used to access these class methods
     */
    public Character(){
        this(50,50,3,300,169);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a more complex Character that takes in more specific information about placement and scaling
     * @param x is the x position on the screen
     * @param y is the y position on the screen
     * @param scale1 is the scale factor that everything gets multiplied by
     * @param w is the width of the characters image
     * @param h is the height of the characters image
     */
    public Character(int x, int y, int scale1, int w, int h){
       super();
      try {                
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\Programming\\Final Project\\Top_down\\narwhal.png"));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } 
       scale = scale1;
       imageP = new Point(x,y);
       speed = 10;
       width = w;
       height = h;
    }

/**
 * lets other classes access the Point variable
 * @return the xy points
 */
    public Point getPoint(){
        return this.imageP;
    }

    /**
     * lets other classes access the Image variable
     * @return the image that is viewed
     */   
    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return this.image;
    }

    /**
     * changes the image that is sent to other classes
     */
    public void setImage(BufferedImage img){
        this.image = img;
    }

    /**
     * lets other classes access the speed variable at which the character moves around
     * @param the speed that is changed in other classes
     */
    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    /**
     * lets other classes access the speed variable
     * @return the xy points
     */
    public int getSpeed(){
        return this.speed;
    }

    /**
     * lets other classes access the width variable
     * @return the width of the image
     */
    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * lets other classes access the height variable
     * @return the height of the image
     */
    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You draw the image at x, y. But you increment imageP.x and imageP.y. Which one is it?

Comment: sorry i was just messing around with that(i thought that was giving me an erro earlier) they both are the same thing, in my constructor i set x equal to imageP.x and the same for y

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Simply setting one of the variables equal to the value of the other variable does not mean the first variable will change when you update the second. In the code you posted, you're updating one variable but drawing with another. If that's not what you're actually running, I suggest posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).